# ON Update not running in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've looked at the documentation on postgresql, and I can't figure out why my CREATE TABLE is not running.

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
    content VARCHAR(100),
    changed_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE SET CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Is there a way to format this so it will work?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) did you find that syntax?

Comment: No. The only way to do this is with a trigger.